# Is there a way to avoid HUP once you used O_NONBLOCK on a socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, nonblocking

When I use sockets in blocking mode, I can have a simple system that does something like this:

```
client            server

A -------------------> B
      register

A <------------------> B
   (various messages)

A -------------------> B
      unregister
```

Just after the `unregister` message is sent, the process A can quit immediately and yet B receives the message as expected.

If I turn on non-blocking mode on A's socket, B never receives `unregister` if A send that message and then quits immediately (I tested by adding a `sleep(1)` after sending `unregister`, in that case it works as expected.) So, more or less, my client cannot cleanly unregister itself.

Note: when B `poll()` A's socket, I get a Hanged Up signal (POLLHUP) instead of the last `unregister` message, then the hang up.

I tried to add a call to turn blocking mode back on, and somehow it makes no difference. I use the following code to change the blocking mode:

```
int optval(0 or 1);
ioctl(get_socket(), FIONBIO, &optval);
```

Just in case, I tried with `fcntl()` too, although I'm sure that tweaks the same flag as far as the kernel is concerned.

```
int flags(fcntl(get_socket(), F_GETFL));
flags |= O_NONBLOCK;   // use this line to turn ON
flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;  // use this line to turn OFF
fcntl(get_socket(), F_SETFL, flags);
```

As a side note, I send and receive my messages using the `read()` and `write()` functions.

---

Update:

For those interested, the test is now in our git:

Server: https://sourceforge.net/p/snapcpp/code/ci/master/tree/snapwebsites/tests/test_shutdown_server.cpp
Client: https://sourceforge.net/p/snapcpp/code/ci/master/tree/snapwebsites/tests/test_shutdown_client.cpp

These use the snap library, mainly the snap_communicator which depends on tcp client/server:

tcp: https://sourceforge.net/p/snapcpp/code/ci/master/tree/snapwebsites/lib/tcp_client_server.cpp
communicator: https://sourceforge.net/p/snapcpp/code/ci/master/tree/snapwebsites/lib/snap_communicator.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are discovering, `send` on a socket only queues the data to be sent. It doesn't actually mean the server got it. This is true for blocking and non-blocking sockets.

Several possibilities:

1. Make sure you call `close` on the socket before your client program exits. You didn't say in your question if this was happening, but it's probably a good idea.
2. If #1 doesn't work, use the `SO_LINGER` option on the socket.  Set a timeout interval appropriate.

Something like the following

```
  struct linger ling;
  ling.l_onoff = 1;
  ling.l_linger = 3; // 3 second wait for data to finish being set.
  setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &ling, sizeof(ling));
```

3. An alternative to #2 is to modify your protocol such that the client gets some sort of acknowledgement message from the server before closing the socket and exiting.  Or for simplicity, the client waits for the server closes the socket before exiting.  (`recv` will return 0 when the server closes the socket)

My recommendation is to make sure you have implemented #1.  If that doesn't it to it for you, evaluate #3.  #2, if nothing else.

Comment: There's a long explanation of this at http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable (note that it might not be as simple as enabling SO_LINGER in all situations - especially if you're using non-blocking sockets)

Comment: Ah! Actually `A` can wait for the HUP since once unregistered, `B` closes the socket of `A`. That makes the most sense in my situation!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you aren't actually closing the socket prior to exiting. All the shenanigans with SO_LINGER shouldn't be necessary in normal circumstances.

Comment: I use C++ so it's kind of hard to miss the destructor... unless the object is never deleted. Only if the object is not deleted my event loop does not exit. Since the process terminates normally, I'm sure it happens. I added some logs to see and I'm 100% sure now. That being said, the HUP signal is what I really need to use. So A sends `unregister` and then waits on the HUP instead of just exiting immediately. I updated my test and it now works as expected.

Comment: All of that said, I did not add anything in regard to lingering. I agree that it is not required.